# JDKのバージョンをどう選択すれば良いですか？

Tags: java, spring-boot

JavaのWEBアプリケーションを開発しようと思っています。
その際にJDKのバージョンを何を選択すれば良いか分からなく教えて頂けないでしょうか。

構成として次のように考えています。

フレームワーク：SpringBoot
データベース：Oracle 19C
ミドルウェア：Apache-Tomcat
ブラウザ：ChromeかEdge
Java：なるべく新しく、安定しているもの。無償版
その他：マスタデータを登録更新するシステムで、複雑なことは考えていません。

追記）APサーバ、DBサーバ共にOSはWindowsServer2016です。

Comment: ご承知とは思いますが商用利用において Oracle JDK はもう無償では提供されません。その辺どう考えているか追記すると良い回答が付きそうです。

Comment: 早速の回答で有難うございます。
現在動いている古いWEBシステムを新たに作り直すことを考えています。そのためのプロト開発を個人的にやろうと思っています。
正式に採用された際には有償版で本格的に構築していく形になると考えています。

Comment: 参考 https://teratail.com/questions/306826

Answer (score 1):

あくまで、参考レベルでその条件での私だったらの判断です。

各構成で必要なJDKバージョンを洗い出します。

---

Spring Boot

- ver.2.3.0（2020/5にリリース）：JDK14サポート(LTSのJDK8,11は完全サポート)
- ver 2.2.0：JDK13サポート(LTSのJDK8,11は完全サポート)
  https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/15/spring-boot-2-3-0-available-now
  https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/16/spring-boot-2-2-0

Oracle 19C

- JDBC : ojdbc8.jarを使用（対応JDK8以降）
  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tdpjd/using-java-with-oracle-database.html#GUID-8C73108B-E0F3-4CD5-A813-909B339339BB

Tomcat

- Ver.10(Alpha) : 対応JDK8以降
- Ver.9 : 対応JDK8以降
  https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Java

- OracleJDK : Java 11以降の「Oracle JDK(LTS版)」は、Oracle社と有償サポート契約を結んだユーザーにのみ提供されるようになる。
- OpenJDK　 : Java 11から「Oracle JDK」と同じ機能と品質を備えたオープンソース実装「OpenJDK」がリリースされバイナリが無償で提供される。
  　
  各JDKの比較
  https://www.ossnews.jp/compare/Oracle_JDK/OpenJDK

---

こうまとめてみると、JDK8以降なら各プロダクトは動くことがわかります。
ただ、Javaの商用問題があるので、JDK11以降であればOracleとOpenJDKの機能差異は小さくすることができます。
（同等とは思いますが、正式採用時にOracle版に切り替えた際には、動作検証は必要と考える）

以上を踏まえて。。JDK11以降の新機能を使用するなどなければ
私であれば、安定寄りにJDK11にすると思います。

参考までに。

Comment: とても参考になりました。JDK８がサポート長いので決めました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: Teratail側でも議論されてましたが、決めたようならなによりです。